# PDO bindValue() is not working

Tags: php, pdo

The bindVlaue() is not giving me any result.
here is my code.

```
    public function query($sql, $values = array()){
        $this->_error = false;
        echo $sql . "<br />";
        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){
            if(count($values)){
                $x = 1;
                foreach($values as $value){
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $value);
                    $x++;
                }
            }
            echo $this->_query->queryString;
            die();
        }
    }
query("SELECT name FROM passengers WHERE id = ? AND username = ?", array('1', 'Mohsin'));
```

I'm echoing , but both time, it is echoing the same sql which i'm passing in the function.

Comment: The query string won't change, the ? are just place holders and the 'replacement' is done internally.

Comment: I don't see something like `$this->_query->execute();` anywhere.  Am I missing something?  Without it the query will not be run.  I also don't see where data is actually extracted, like `$this->_query->fetchAll();`.

Comment: Thanks dear @NigelRen , I thought it would be visible.

Comment: @JBH I was just trying to see the value before executing, I was thinking the value will be replaced visually.